# Is there any reason why there isn't a cross-platform implementation of DirectX?

Tags: opengl, directx, graphics

Similar to how Mono can compile C# to various platforms, why isn't there an API that conforms to DirectX's specifications but can produce binaries for all platforms?

I understand that there is OpenGL but Microsoft is pushing DirectX with marketing and technologies such as XNA (which is now dead). Also, I understand that engines are supposed to support multiple backends (DirectX, OpenGL, Mantle, etc.) but that takes work..

Comment: I would actually make the argument that OpenGL and its variations are likely seeing far more use than DirectX when it comes to game development these days. Ever since mobile and web based development started making people rich, coupled with how easy it is to get started developing for these platforms. Also, this wonderful comic strip explains this problem well https://xkcd.com/927/

Comment: Valve has recently open-sourced [ToGL](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/ToGL), their DirectX-to-OpenGL translation layer. But it is still far away from fully supporting everything DirectX has to offer and needs considerable cleanup.

Comment: XNA is dead, but Monogame lives on. And supports more platforms (albeit at a cost).

Comment: In addition to what @ashes999 said, the cost is only for iOS and Android, and only because of Xamarin. For Win/Mac/Linux, it's still free.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Similar to how Mono can compile C# to various platforms, why isn't
>   there an API that conforms to DirectX's specifications but can produce
>   binaries for all platforms?

First, I assume you mean something like an implementation of D3D that can be *compiled* on all platforms, since producing binaries that run on all platforms is not the domain of the graphics API (that's a language toolchain issue).

The answer is because nobody has written one. Strictly speaking, however, the [Wine project](http://www.winehq.org/) and things like Transgaming's Cider have these sorts of emulation layers you are asking for, but they are not exposes as independent APIs.

Why hasn't anybody written one? Well, it's a lot of work and the reward is so small as to not be worth the effort. Unless such an implementation were done by hardware vendors, it would always be less efficient because it would necessitate wrapping one API in terms of another. Back around the time of the D3D10 release, there were a handful of projects (such as the "Alky Project," who main site appears to now be defunct) that tried to support D3D10 on older OSs like XP. They did this via OpenGL-based emulation of the D3D API calls, it just wasn't very good. I haven't looked at Valve's [ToGL](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/ToGL) at all yet, but it's basically the same idea and consequently will always have that fundamental flaw.

Driver vendors have no particularly motivation to implement such a project *without* emulation, and they'd need to do it in cooperation with Microsoft (the D3D functional specification is not public), who *also* have no strong motivation to do so at this point. Given what AMD is doing with Mantle, it's possible that driver vendors want to trend *away*, at least in part, from providing standardized APIs and focus instead of investing effort in exposing ways developers can take advantage of their unique hardware capabilities.

Thus, any attempt at building such an API is only going to serve two real purposes:

- *It will let you use an API whose style you prefer*. But this is being done at the expense of performance and reliability (since emulating the specific behavior of all D3D calls for all possible inputs is very difficult, even when writing a D3D-to-D3D wrapper like SlimDX, which I used to be a part of) by introducing a competing abstraction. This means this would usually be a poor engineering basis for the selection of such a wrapper API.
- *It will assist in the porting of a game* written on Windows to another platform. Of course, so would using OpenGL from the get-go. We'll have to see what the upcoming D3D 12 adds to the table, but in general if you have any inkling that you might want cross-platform development in the future, you should probably stick to OpenGL. If you've already made the choice and invested in D3D, this can be a reasonable engineering rationale, but you still suffer the performance issue.

Essentially, anybody who has the capability of producing a good implementation of a D3D emulation layer would likely realize also that its use-case was basically limited to facilitating ports, which means adoption would be relatively low and it probably just isn't worth the effort for most people to consider building.

Answer (score 0):

Well eventhough I doubt the usefulness of such project, DirectX and OpenGL implementations are not provided by the community, it is provided by the companies who make graphics hardware (Nvidia, AMD, Intel). And the *keyword here is **Business***...

So you will either wait for a software implementation of DirectX (or emulation on top of OpenGL), which limits its usefulness IMHO, or, wait for one of the companies to do that, and they won't'; for many reasons!

- It's not useful from their point of view, what revenue could such an
  involved project benefit them?
- OpenGL already exists and is already on par with DirectX.
- From their point of view they better provide an API that exposes more features/power of their hardware (e.g. AMD Mantle), it really makes sense from business point of view, rather than spending years developing a DirectX implementation that will probably be sub-par in the first years, won't help *Sell* more GPUs.

Even with cross platform DirectX, people will still optimize and even rewrite parts of the application for multiple platforms, it will be the same as the "cross platform" OpenGL which will you get different results on different platforms. I also suspect the big developers with already stable code bases will not switch as it gives them very little benefit.

Another interesting answer to read about the [history of DirectX vs OpenGL](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/60544/why-do-game-developers-prefer-windows/88055#88055).